# Need form to display error if value is greater then another form value

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I am looking for a way that when a form is submitted it will check if the value entered in "spaces" > "spaces left".  If it is show an error and do not submit form, if value is <= submit the form.

I am 100% lost and do not even know where to start and searching is proving to be little help.

So far the form is php, html and javascript.

Comment: What you have tried ? if nothing try with jquery or pure javascript using onSubmit event and return false if fails otherwise true to continue with submitting.

Comment: Looks like using pure javascript was the way to go.  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using isset and !empty then doing something with the $_POST data?

Answer (score 0):

```
function checkForm(form)
{
var spaces = parseInt(form.spaces.value);
var avbspaces = parseInt(form.avbspaces.value);
 if(form.spaces.value > form.avbspaces.value) {
  alert("Error: There are not enough spaces.");
          return false;
```

}

```
return true;
```

}

Within the form:

```
<FORM NAME="form" id="form" action="submit.php" onsubmit="return checkForm(this);">
```